# How to make conditional probability of continuous variable match intuition?

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

I'm stuck with the following "physical problem": I have a set $E=\{1, \ldots, n\}$, a function $f : E \to \mathbb{R}$ and a secret value $x_0\in E$. My goal is to find $x_0$.

Furthermore, I know that for $x\neq x_0$ (resp. $x= x_0$), $f(x)$ is supposed to be drawn from a fixed continuous distribution $D$ (resp. $D'$).

Hence my first thought was to sort all $x$ according to:

$$\Pr(x=x_0\mid\forall x'\in E, f(x'))$$

At this point I have already a problem, because I don't know how to formalize the intuitive meaning of $\Pr(\cdot\mid\forall x\in E,f(x))$ (I can't find any way to write the RHS as an event).

And then applying a kind of Bayes formula for continuous variables:

$$\Pr(x=x_0\mid\forall x'\in E, f(x'))=\frac{\text{Pr}(\forall x'\in E,f(x')\mid x=x_0) \Pr(x=x_0)}{\sum_{x''}\Pr(\forall x'\in E, f(x')\mid x''=x_0) \Pr(x''=x_0)}$$

Thus, as I think my model implies to choose $x_0$ uniformly at random in $E$, only $\Pr(\forall x'\in E,f(x')\mid x=x_0)$ depends on $x$. And my intuition tells me that if my model was correctly formalized, it could be expressed with the CDF $F_D$ and $F_D'$. How can I do this?

I'm not familiar with statistics, so I'm expecting an explanation from probability theory.

Comment: What does it mean for $f$ to be 'known'? It seems that $f$ is determined by what $D, D', x_0$ are.

Comment: @MeesdeVries: I removed the adjective. I just wanted to pointed that $f$ had an explicit formula, depending on his input $x$ and on some uniform random variables (but it's probably misleading).

Comment: So if I am correct, you have $n-1$ observations sampled from $D$, and one sampled from $D'$, but you don't know which is which, and you want to find a most likely candidate for which one was sampled from $D'$?

Comment: @MeesdeVries: Yes, that's it. I know it's a standard problem in statistics, but what I'm looking for is not only a score, but also a probability distribution on $E$ quantifying what I call $P(x=x_0|\forall x',f(x'))$.

Comment: Do you have a sort of prior assumption that each of $1,\ldots,n$ is equally likely?

Comment: @MeesdeVries: Well it comes from a "real life" problem, and assuming that $x_0$ is uniformly chosen in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ looks ok to me.

Comment: One difference between \text{Pr} and \Pr is this: $$ \begin{align} \text{2\text{Pr} A :} & \qquad 2\text{Pr} A \\ \text{2\Pr A :} & \qquad 2\Pr A \end{align} $$ Also note the use of \mid, as in my edit to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have somewhat nicer notation, let $Y = (Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$ be the random variables which you write as $f(1),\ldots,f(n)$, and let $X$ be the random variable which you write as $x_0$. Then, let $y = (y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ be your observations. We have for each $x \in E$ that
\begin{align*}
P(X=x \mid Y=y) &= \frac{f_Y(y \mid X = x)P(X =x)}{\sum_{x' \in E}f_Y(y \mid X = x')P(X=x')} \\\\
&= \frac{f_{D'}(y_x)\prod_{x' \in E,x'\neq x}f_D(y_{x'})}{\sum_{x' \in E} f_{D'}(y_{x'})\prod_{x'' \in E,x''\neq x'}f_D(y_{x''}),}\\\\
&= \frac{f_{D'}(y_x)}{f_D(y_x)\sum_{x' \in E}\frac{f_{D'}(y_{x'})}{f_D(y_{x'})}}\\\\
&= \frac{f_{D'}(y_x)}{f_D(y_x)}\Bigg/{\sum_{x' \in E}\frac{f_{D'}(y_{x'})}{f_D(y_{x'})}}
\end{align*}
In other words, the probability that $X = x$ is given by the ratio $f_{D'}(y_x)/f_D(y_x)$, "how many times more likely $D'$ is to give $y_x$ than $D$", with all these ratios normalized so that they add up to 1.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I've been looking for. Actually I think my main problem was my gap in continuous laws, didn't even know it was possible to write $P(X=x|Y=y)$ as $(Y=y)$ doesn't look measurable.

Comment: @Arvik, it no longer follows the definition $P(X = x \mid Y = y) = P(X = x \land Y = y)/P(Y = y)$ since, as you mention, $P(Y = y) = 0$; however, you can still define what $P( \cdot \mid Y = y)$ means in many contexts, and then this is one of the conclusions.